# What is the cardinality of non-singleton subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals, infinity, natural-numbers

I am studying a course on ZF Set Theory (without the Axiom of Choice) and am currently looking at the cardinalities of infinite sets. One question that I came across is the following:

> Determine the cardinality of non-singleton subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

If we let $ \mathbb{N}^{(1)}$ denote the set of singleton subsets of the natural numbers, then the set of interest is $ \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N} ) \setminus \mathbb{N} ^{(1)}$

We know the following:

$$| \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N} ) | = 2^{\aleph _0}$$

$$ \text{and } | \mathbb{N^{(1)}} | \leq | \mathbb{N} | = \aleph _0 $$

Based on this, it is my suspicion that:

$$ | \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N} ) \setminus \mathbb{N} ^{(1)}| = | \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N} ) |= 2^{\aleph _0}$$

But I am unsure how to formalise this and would be grateful for any help in doing so.

Comment: I'd use the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem.

Comment: I considered that, but still struggled to construct suitable functions to produce an argument @DustanLevenstein

Comment: Just fyi, an easy injection $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \hookrightarrow \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \mathbb N^{(1)}$ is given by $S \mapsto \{1, 2\} \cup \{x \mid x-3 \in S\}$. I finagled this so that it doesn't matter whether you consider $0 \in \mathbb N$ or not. Of course I'm not using elementary Peano Arithmetic operations, but this should be easy enough to translate to ZF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is as follows: Pick a countably infinite set, $A\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ that is disjoint from $\mathbb{N}^{(1)}$. One can partition $A$ into two disjoint sets $K,M$ both of cardinality $\aleph_{0}$, now construct a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N })\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N })\setminus \mathbb{N}^{(1)}$ as follows: Map everything in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N })\setminus \mathbb{N}^{(1)})\setminus A$ to itself, bijectively map $A$ to $K$ and $\mathbb{N}^{(1)}$ to $M$ (using the fact that they all have the same cardinality).

(Note how generalisable this proof is)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume you require $A$ to be countably **infinite** rather than just countable?

Comment: Well, yes. Note that countable is often used for countably infinite. I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Just a quick note on your last comment regarding the proof being generalisable, could you clarify what you meant by that? I can see how you might generalise to $\mathbb{N}^{(2)} , \mathbb{N} ^{(3)}$, etc. but is there more to it than that? (where $\mathbb{N}^{(2)}$ is the set of doubleton subsets of the natural numbers)

Comment: Not what I am saying, remember since those sets are countable it is equivalent. What I am saying is that if we have a set $X$ of cardinality greater than $\aleph_{0}$ then removing a countable set from that set gives a set of the same cardinality.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense